# Limitations of work-item load in GPU? CUDA/OpenCL

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a compute-intensive image algorithm that, for each pixel, needs to read many distant pixels. The distance is dependent on a constant defined at compile-time. My OpenCL algorithm performs well, but at a certain maximum distance - resulting in more heavy for loops - the driver seems to bail out. The screen goes black for a couple of seconds and then the command queue never finishes. A balloon message reveals that the driver is unhappy:

*"Display driver AMD driver stopped responding and has successfully recovered."*

(Running this on OpenCL 1.1 with an `AMD FirePro V4900 (FireGL V) Graphics Adapter`.)

1. Why does this occur?
2. Is it possible to, beforehand, tell the driver that everything is ok?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known "feature" under Windows (not sure about Linux) - if the video driver stops responding, the OS will reset it. Except that, since OpenCL (and CUDA) is implemented by the driver, a kernel that takes too long will look like a frozen driver. There is a watchdog timer that keeps track of this (5 seconds, I believe).

Your options are:

1. You need to make sure that your kernels are not too time-consuming (best).
2. You can turn-off the watchdog timer: [Timeout Detection and Recovery of GPUs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx).
3. You can run the kernel on a GPU that is not hooked up to a display.

I suggest you go with 1.

Comment: Thanks! TDR was indeed the problem. For now I will stick to #2, but #3 is appealing. I suppose the GPU could even run a bit faster when no display is hooked up.